# How to get setInterval to run callback function once before applying delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am running setInterval in useEffect hook to loop a function, however, I want to be able to run that function once first before applying the delay (interval). Is there a way I can run the function once in the useEffect hook before applying the delay?

I have tried running the function once inside the hook before the setInterval function but it didn't give me the results I hoped for. Same goes for running the function outside the useEffect hook.

```
  const myText = props.text;
  const textTimeout = 100;
  const funTextInterval = textTimeout * myText.length
  const [quickText, setQuickText] = useState([]);

  const setDelay = (i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
       myFunction();
     , textTimeout * i);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < myText.length + 1; i++) {
        setDelay(i);
      }
    }, funTextInterval);    
  }, []);
```

I expect the `forloop` to run once before the delay from setInterval kicks in, but the delay occurs before the `forloop`

Comment: Are you sure the delay isn't coming from the `setTimeout()` rather than the interval?

Comment: ^^ That.  A combination of `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` is causing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the for-loop logic in a method and call that before setInterval and inside setInterval

```
const myText = props.text;
  const textTimeout = 100;
  const funTextInterval = textTimeout * myText.length
  const [quickText, setQuickText] = useState([]);

  const setDelay = (i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
       myFunction();
     , textTimeout * i);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const loop = () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < myText.length + 1; i++) {
        setDelay(i);
      }
    }
    loop();
    setInterval(() => {
      loop();
    }, funTextInterval);    
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can separate your logic like this:

```
  const myText = props.text;
  const textTimeout = 100;
  const funTextInterval = textTimeout * myText.length
  const [quickText, setQuickText] = useState([]);

  function applyTextEffect() {
      for (let i = 0; i < myText.length + 1; i++) {
        setTimeout(myFunction, textTimeout * i);
      }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    applyTextEffect()  // call it here immediately to get the effect you want.
    setInterval(applyTextEffect, funTextInterval);    
  }, []);
```

But note, this component will create an unwanted effect by calling your text effect function on every update. UseEffect works in every update. Better to have a isMounted state variable and implement logic around it to apply effect only once.

EDIT: It's also wise to store interval id returned from setInterval function and clear it in return of useEffect. Otherwise when your component is going to be destroyed, you'll get exceptions

Answer (score 0):

write a separate function only with for loop.
call that function before you call useEffect().
from inside useEffect() -> setInterval(), call the new method.

Untested code is given below for illustration.

```
const myText = props.text;
const textTimeout = 100;
const funTextInterval = textTimeout * myText.length
const [quickText, setQuickText] = useState([]);

const setDelay = (i) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
     myFunction();
   , textTimeout * i);
};

runloop(){
  for (let i = 0; i < myText.length + 1; i++) {
    setDelay(i);
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    runloop()
  }, funTextInterval);    
}, []);

runloop();
```